# Android - SQLite Not Inserting Rows

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to take a `CSV` file and importing that data into Android's `SQLite3`. The app runs fine without any `SQLite` error in the `LogCat`. I'm not sure why the data isn't being inputted. I made sure that the program actually tries to do the insert `execSQL` by deliberately causing a `SQLite` syntax error in the insert command and it showed up on the `LogCat`. So it does find the `CSV` file and it does get to the insert `execSQL`. I'm just not sure why it isn't inserting.

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_MOVIES = "CREATE TABLE movies (_id integer primary key autoincrement, title text not null, year integer not null, director text not null);";

public DbAdapter(Context ctx){
    super(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    mContext = ctx;
    this.mDb = getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_MOVIES);

    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mContext.getAssets().open("movies.csv")));
        String line;

        while((line = in.readLine()) !=null) {
            String[] RowData = line.split(",");

            moviesID = RowData[0];
            moviesTitle = RowData[1];
            moviesYear = RowData[2];
            moviesDirector = RowData[3];
            db.execSQL("insert into movies(_id, title, year, director) values(" + moviesID + ", '" + moviesTitle + "', " + moviesYear + ", '" + moviesDirector + "');");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Caught any exception?

Comment: No exceptions anywhere that I know of. LogCat and Console is clean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you create table says that the `_id` is **auto incremented**, why do you want to insert that?

Try something like this:-

```
db.execSQL("insert into movies(title, year, director) values(" + "'" + moviesTitle + "', " + moviesYear + ", '" + moviesDirector + "');");
```

where `_id` is removed from the `insert query`.

Comment: You are one sexy man, you know that? I removed autoincrement. It worked. Can't believe I missed that. But that's what's great about giving your code a fresh eye.